# FeignClient in spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to migrate from spring boot 1.5 tio 2.0 and faced problem: I changed version of **spring-cloud-netflix-core** from *1.3.4.RELEASE* to *2.0.1.RELEASE*:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Unfortunately, feign library imports failed:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient;
```

There is no library .feign in new 2.0.1 version. What should I use instead? (connot leave old cloud version because of conflict with spring boot autoconfiguration)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since the `2.x` release Spring Cloud moved the netflix feign classes to their own project.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign

You need to update your re-import with the correct package

`org.springframework.cloud.openfeign`

Answer (score 17):

You need to import feign as an independent dependency starting from 2.X release:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```